# How to run a unix command and which requires dynamic console input in python and how to run this without manual intervention

Tags: python, subprocess

**Command: /opt/oracle/admin/bin/dboc  configure dbfs --home /oracle/client/18.3.0/**

> When we run the above command on linux terminal it expects 3 inputs one by one as below
>
> Validating DBFS Client : asdjascads
>
> Enter Connectstring for dbaas : akxhsakc
>
> Enter password : xbvcascha

Below is the python code that i have developed and it just is failing to wait and expect the inputs , this command expects the input and when i press enter , it just shows the expected input string and exits but does not wait

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
def run_dboc_command(args):

    command = ['/opt/oracle/admin/bin/dboc'] + args
    result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    return result.stdout.decode(), result.stderr.decode()

args=['configure', 'dbfs', '--home', ' /oracle/client/18.3.0/']
stdout,stderr = run_dboc_command(args)

print ("Output:")
print (stdout)
print ("Error:")
print (stderr)
```

Also , Is it possible to run the command from python script without any manual intervention. Like we will send all the expected inputs as arguments and it does not expect anythig

Comment: This is not a linux command but was shipped by Oracle and its needs to be inputted  when asked. , Is there a way we can overcome this and make it part of python code